# Matrix values as a result of comparing values in a vector

Tags: r, matrix

I have a vector rescribing the 'score' of each of the three points:

```
v <- c(1, 6, 2)
```

What I would like to do is compare the three values against each other and create matrix, setting the value in the matrix to 1 if the score compared is larger and 0 if not.

like so:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]   0  6>1? 2>1?
 [2,] 1>6?   0  2>6?
 [3,] 1>2? 6>2?   0
```

Resulting in a matrix like so:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    0    1    1
 [2,]    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    1    0
```

I'm coming up stumped, whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: I do not really get what you want to do, do you want to compare each line to the score vector, or each column? Or something else?

Comment: @Chelmy88 Sorry that it wasn't described very well, a column wise comparison would be preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to transpose the matrix to do column-wise comparison and after comparison transpose it again to get the same structure as the original one.

```
+(t(t(m) > v))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    1
#[2,]    1    0    1
#[3,]    1    0    0
```

---

Or we can also use `sweep` here

```
+(sweep(m, 2, v, ">"))
```

---

Based on the updated question, we can use `outer`

```
+(outer(v, v, `<`))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    1
#[2,]    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0
```

Comment: We posted different answers??!?!! How did that happen... :D

Comment: I have realised that I was asking the wrong question, I've updated the main text.

Comment: @tom91 We can use `outer` in that case. Can you also update your expected output ?

Comment: Thank you, I had been looking at outer. I'm I right that this is doing row comparison rather than column as the last one was?

Comment: Now you have only `v` which is a vector so there is no row now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea where we flatten the matrix and use R's recycling power to compare with the vector. Once we do that, we cast back to matrix, i.e.

```
matrix(as.integer(t(c(m)) > v), nrow = nrow(m), byrow = TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    1
#[2,]    1    0    1
#[3,]    1    0    0
```

Comment: I have realised that I was asking the wrong question, I've updated the main text.

Answer (score 1):

A column wise comparison can be obtained with:

```
1*(m>v)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    1
#[2,]    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    1    0
```

Comment: Not exactly, can you check your output?

Comment: Using `m <- matrix(c(0,5,8,5,0,4,8,4,0), ncol = 3, nrow = 3)`, `v <- c(1, 6, 2)`, and `1*(m>v)` I get the output in my answer. Don't you? I added it because for me your answer is a raw wise comparison

Comment: I have realised that I was asking the wrong question, I've updated the main text

Comment: So I think what I propose gives the expected result, no?

Comment: OP initially wanted a column-wise comparison and you had shown row-wise comparison. Although, now they have changed question completely.

Comment: For me the output is a column wise comparison, not raw wise (I compare each column of the matrix to the vector taken in a vertical form and put one if the matrix element is bigger than the vector element)